# Jquery Validation: AddMethod message override standard message

Tags: jquery, validation

I have 2 input forms that require numeric values (between 0-3):

```
<input type="text" id="number1" name="number1" placeholder="0" maxlength="1" class="optionsNumber" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 51">
<input type="text" id="number2" name="number2" placeholder="0" maxlength="1" class="optionsNumber" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 51">
```

I am then using Jquery Validate addMethod to check if the combined values of number1 and number2 are less than 4:

```
<script>


$(document).ready(function() {

    $.validator.addMethod("check_months", function (value, element, param) {
        var number1 = $("#number1").val() || 0;
        var number2 = $("#number2").val() || 0;
        return this.optional(element) || parseInt(number1)+parseInt(number2) < 4;
    }, "The total number allocated to number1 and number2 cannot be more than 3.");

    $("#Form").validate({
        onkeyup: function(element) {
            this.element(element);
        },
        onfocusout: function(element) {
            this.element(element);
        },
        rules: {
            number1: {
                check_months: true,
            },
            number2: {
                check_months: true,
            },
        },
        messages: {
            number1: "Please enter the number you require number1 (max 3)",
            number2: "Please enter the number you require number2 (max 3)"
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            var placement = $(element).data('error');
            if (placement) {
                $(placement).append(error)
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

If the input field for number1 contains 2 and the input field for number2 contains 2 then the combined value is 4, Thus I want to show the addMethod message (The total number allocated to number1 and number2 cannot be more than 3.) but the errors I see are the validate message (Please enter the number you require number1/2 (max 3)).

How do I override the validate message with the addMethod message?

UPDATE: by commenting out the standard messages the addMethod message is shown, but what if a user wants both:

```
messages: {
            //number1: "Please enter the number you require number1 (max 3)",
            //number2: "Please enter the number you require number2 (max 3)"
        },
```

Comment: In your addMethod for number 1 and number 2  you are fetching same number 2 value.

Comment: Thanks @SangitaKendre that was a typo where I tried to clean up the code to make it easier to read - fixed now but issue is still present.

Answer (score 0):

While using validate function, you have specified global error message for each field, it overrides default messages. Below code worked for me. Please check.

```
$.validator.addMethod("check_months", function (value, element, param) {
            var number1 = $("#number1").val() || 0;
            var number2 = $("#number2").val() || 0;
            return this.optional(element) || parseInt(number1)+parseInt(number2) < 4;
        }, "The total number allocated to number1 and number2 cannot be more than 3.");

        $("#Form").validate({
            onkeyup: function(element) {
                this.element(element);
            },
            onfocusout: function(element) {
                this.element(element);
            },
            rules: {
                number1: {
                    required: true,
                    check_months: true,
                },
                number2: {
                    required: true,
                    check_months: true,
                },
            },
            messages: {
                number1: { required: "Please enter the number you require number1 (max 3)", },
                number2:{ required:  "Please enter the number you require number2 (max 3)"}
            },
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                var placement = $(element).data('error');
                if (placement) {
                    $(placement).append(error)
                } else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I dropped the number1 and number2 within the messages area and it worked. Thanks for your help